# Background text on form select

Tags: html, css, forms, woocommerce

I'm trying to add a downward-pointing chevron (basically a down arrow) from the [FontAwesome](http://fontawesome.io/icons/) icon set to a form select box. I've removed the default styling from the select box and added the icon as a pseudo-element after the form. It's working as-intended in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/56rxK/2/), but not on the site I'm working on.

It seems like the issue may be that the `background: transparent;` styling on the select isn't working the same on the site as in the fiddle, but I'm not sure why that would be the case. I know I could make the icon visible by increasing the z-index, but then the select dropdown won't show when the icon is clicked (as it does in the fiddle).

Edit: I need to have the dropdown show up when the icon is clicked; this is the case in the fiddle, but doesn't work with a higher z-index on the pseudo-element

Edit 2: Example of accepted solution is in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/56rxK/3/); also removed link to production website.

Any thoughts on what's happening here?

Comment: I'm using the code (`\f078`) for that icon in the content of the `:after` pseudo-element - http://astronautweb.co/snippet/font-awesome/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems as you have 2 different problems - positioning and functionality. Currently your website doesn't display the arrow at all. And even if it did, clicking on the arrow would not open the dropdown list. Simply putting it on top, may work in some browsers, but AFAIK would not be a cross-browser solution.

Per functionality, add `'pointer-events:none'` to the arrow alement. This will make sure that it doesn't handle any clicks and they will be propogated to the select elemnt.

Regarding your positioning:

Instead of changing the z-index, simply set the min-width to N pixels and remove the absolute positioning from the arrow.

In CSS selector `ordering:after`

```
Remove `position:absoulte;`.
```

In CSS selector `select.orderby`

Change `width:100%;` to `min-width: 200px;` (or any width you need)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm not seeing how this allows you to click on the icon and see the dropdown. Do you have a fiddle?

Comment: @nicolekanderson my answer was regarding your positioning not the functionality. I guess wasn't absolutely clear on your question, I will revise my answer.

Comment: No problem; I edited the original post to make that more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You have `z-index: -1` on this `.woocommerce-ordering:after` in your css. Make it 0 or larger than 0 and it works.

Comment: As I mentioned above, setting the z-index higher means that the select dropdown won't show when the icon is clicked.